# Custom merging JObjects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Got two variables of JObject type. Actually readed from file JSON settings. 
First one is global settings, second one is custom settings. 
Task is to merge them together without overriding existing properties, only add new to global. 
But in [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) found setting for merging [JArray](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm) only.
Only one comes to mind, is to write own merge function.

Example:

```
// obj1
{
    "prop1": "true",
    "prop2": "hello"
}

// obj2
{
    "prop2": "bye",
    "prop3": "100",
}

// merged result
{
    "prop1": "true",
    "prop2": "hello",
    "prop3": "100",
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just equivalent to merging them in reverse order?  I.e. if you do `obj2.Merge(obj1)` then `obj2` will contain all properties & values from `obj1` plus any properties & values originally in `obj2` and not present in `obj1`.

Comment: @dbc you are right. Thx,